# Why do i get an error no match for 'operator^'

Tags: c++, operators, xor, operator-precedence

I am getting an error

```
10:13: error: no match for 'operator^' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'int')
10:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
             from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:161:3: note: std::_Ios_Iostate std::operator^(std::_Ios_Iostate, std::_Ios_Iostate)
operator^(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
^
```

the code is

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
int a=1;
int b=2;

std::cout<<a^b;
}
```

What are the operands that can be used with `operator ^` ?

Comment: ^ ha a low operator precedence: Use parentheses std::cout << (a^b);

Comment: The actual question "What are the operands that can be used with operator ^ ?" is to broad.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator^`. So `std::cout<<a^b;` is equivalent with `(std::cout<<a)^b;`; `(std::cout<<a)` will return `std::cout` by reference, which is a `std::basic_ostream<char>`; Just as the error message said, you can't call `operator^` with `std::cout`(`std::basic_ostream<char>`) and `int`.

You could use parentheses to specify the precedence how the operands should be bound to operators.

```
std::cout << (a^b);
//           ~   ~
```